# Correlation of indicators

Tags: regression, correlation

I have a list of countries and for each country I have a number of defects per 1000 certain product (DP indicator) and a number of products per 1000 inhabitants (PI indicator). Is it statistically correct to use a linear regression for these 2 indicators? I get a graph as below:

[image: Linear regression of 2 indicators]

Comment: Visually this is clearly not linear.  You might want to transform one (or perhaps both) of your variables to see whether that makes a difference: investigating reciprocals or logarithms might be ideas to consider

Comment: what confuses me is that the line has this regular shape but I am not sure what does it mean?

Comment: You might be interested in plotting products per defect against products per inhabitant so that the common numbers of products play a comparable role in each value and are linearly related.